# deserealizar array json y vb.net

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net, json, vb.net

Envio a traves de ajax un array que contiene valores que el usuario selecciona de un conjunto de checkbox de esta forma

```
    $("#btnEnviarTelcel").click(function () {        
        var conjuntoFacturas=[];
        $("#form1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function (i) {
            if (this.checked) {

                conjuntoFacturas[i]= $(this).val();

            }
        });

        EnviarReporte(conjuntoFacturas);
        if (selected == '')
            alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');
        return false;
    });

    function EnviarReporte(varValorCheck) {

      var cargando = $("#muestraSeccion").html("<center><img  src='../Images/cargando1.gif' height='50px' width='50px'/><br/>Un momento por favor...<center>");

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'guardarEnvio',
        data: {
          "facturasEnvio": JSON.stringify(varValorCheck),

        },
        success: function(resultado) {

          $("#muestraSeccion").hide().html(resultado).fadeIn("fast");

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

            alert('Not connect: Verify Network.=(');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

            alert('Requested page not found [404].');

          } else {

            alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

          }

        }
      });
    }
```

posterior en la pagina "guardarEnvio"  recupero el array asi:

```
Dim grupoFacturas=Request.Form("facturasEnvio") Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(grupoFacturas) Response.Write(result)
```

y me muestra el siguiente resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como puedo obtener los valores de forma individual? ya que estaria haciendo un update por cada valor que devuelva el array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el evento `click`, te recomiendo agregar los elementos en el array usando la función `push`, sino dejas espacios con valor en `null`, tal y como se ve en tu ejemplo, algo que sera molesto para procesar el array en el server.

```
$("#form1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function (i) {
  if (this.checked) {
    conjuntoFacturas.push($(this).val());
  }
});
```

Finalmente en VB.NET deserializa la lista usando

```
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of String))(grupoFacturas)
```